# Using determinant to calculate surface of a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, determinant

$$\frac 12\left|\begin{matrix} -\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)}{2} &\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2} & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right| $$

With this we calculate the area of a triangle that has vertices:

$$x=-\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)}{2} $$ and $$y=\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2}$$ Is the point of the first vertex

The other vertices of the triangle are the $ x$-intercepts of the lines, namely $(0,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. So the area is simply

$$\frac 12\left|\begin{matrix} -\frac{(\sqrt 2+1)}{2} &\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2} & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right| $$

So my question is, how does this work to calculate this. I already have experience with determinants but never to calculate surface.

Comment: when you said *discriminant*, did you mean *determinant*?  cf. [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Comment: Sorry, yes determinant, I will edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two dimensions it's more simple: Let $\vec a=(a_x,a_y)$ and $\vec b=(b_x,b_y)$ then the area of the parallelogram spanned by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ is just the absolute value of the determinant of these vectors, see [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogramm#Beweis_der_Flächenformel_für_ein_Parallelogramm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogramm#Beweis_der_Fl%C3%A4chenformel_f%C3%BCr_ein_Parallelogramm).

Comment: I think you could change the link to the english version :)

Comment: In the english version the image is missing -- there's no visual proof.

Comment: The german will be okay

Comment: Allow me to redo the edit, because the english version doesn't provide any proof but refers to the Gram-determinant instead.